# select box in model window as list items

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want to make a select box like pop up item, I come accross with this link
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/NaturalLanguageForm/

In that they have done select box overwrite method. when clicking on the food it opens in popup about list of the items. 
can anyone please tell me how to do similar to this with jquery..

Answer (score 0):

how about this 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QCZ87/88/)

```
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"><h1>click for option</h1></div>
  <p > 
      <ul>
          <li> item 1 </li>
           <li> item 2 </li>
           <li> item 3 </li>

      </ul>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Check the ***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sC9xL/154/)***

```
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c"> <a href="#dia" data-rel="dialog" data-theme="b">open the dialog</a>
```

***Script***

```
$('#page1').bind('pageinit', function () {
    picache = "http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/_assets/images/jquery-logo.png";

    $('#pop1,#pop2').bind('popupbeforeposition popupafteropen popupafterclose', function (e) {
        var thm = e.type == 'popupbeforeposition' ? 'b' : (e.type == 'popupafteropen' ? 'd' : 'e'),
            tgt = $(e.target).attr('id');
        style = tgt == 'pop2' ? 'style="color: firebrick; font-size:1.2em;"' : "";

        $('#log').append('<li data-theme="' + thm + '"' + style + '>' + tgt + ": " + e.type + ' raised</li>').listview('refresh');
    });
    $('#log').on('taphold dblclick', function () {
        $(this).find('li').remove();
    });
});
```